# Can I upload my project with Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

[SOLVED] ik it is a stupid question. I have recently finished my project and want to upload it to github (open source). I am a bit unsure if I can upload the project with the Community edition of Visual Studio 2019. Am I allowed to do this I mean it is non commercial use.

Comment: Sure can https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/blob/master/docs/using/publishing-an-existing-project-to-github.md

Comment: Thank you very much :)